# Ubuntu REISUB Issue

Tags: display

I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. Everything was working fine until my system froze while running a model. I waited for 10 minutes and hit alt + prt sc + REISUB. Nothing came on the screen and it went black. I waited for 10 minutes and pressed the power button for force shutdown. And now, there's no display. I can't access Grub, boot menu, bios or anything. Need urgent help.

Comment: It could be a hardware issue. Maybe graphics card or a RAM stick suddenly failed.

Comment: What are my options now? How can i get the system running?

Comment: If you have two or more RAM sticks remove them one at a time and cold start the computer. If it starts again you know which RAM stick to replace.

Comment: I have only 1 ram stick. I removed it and then reinserted it. But it didn't work.